# How to turn back on a previous listener?

Tags: jquery, events, click, listener

Sorry if this has already been posted, but I have seen many of them and attempted to get to use them to get a solution, but none of them have been working for me.

Here are the ways I thought were right (without other coding I was doing). When `F1` is triggered, the click should be disabled. When I `F2` is triggered, it should be enabled:

## 1.

```
$('.head2, .head3').click(function(event) {
    var object = $(this).siblings('.head4');
    if (something) F1();
if (somethingelse)) F2();
    function F1() {
        object.siblings('.head3').children('.primary').off('click');
    }
    function F2() {
        object.siblings('.head3').children('.primary').on('click');
    }
});
```

ISSUE: The click event listener does not turn off.

## 2.

```
$('.head2 li, .head3 li').click(function(event) {
    var object = $(this).parent().siblings('.head4');
    if (something) F1();
if (somethingelse)) F2();
    function F1() {
        object.siblings('.head3').children('.primary').off('click');
    }
    function F2() {
        object.siblings('.head3').children('.primary').on('click');
    }
});
```

ISSUE: `.primary` is not reassigned a click event listener

## 3.

```
func = $('.head2 li, .head3 li').click(function(event) {
    var object = $(this).parent().siblings('.head4');
    if (something) F1();
if (somethingelse)) F2();
    function F1() {
        object.siblings('.head3').children('.primary').off('click');
    }
    function F2() {
        object.siblings('.head3').children('.primary').on('click', func);
    }
});
```

ISSUE: `ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply'`

For a better clarification of what I am doing, I am attempting to turn off a set of `li`s that had the event handler attached to it without turning off the others, ONLY when it is toggled.

Example:

```
<ul class="head">
    <li class="sub1"></div>
    <li class="sub2"></div>
    <li class="sub3"></div>
</div>
```

When you click any of the `li`, something happens, and then `.sub1` has its click event handler removed. Then when you click any of the `li` again, EXCEPT `sub1`, the actions are reversed and `sub1` becomes clickable again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event delegation

```
$('body').on('click','li',function(){
//do the logic for all li elements
});

$('body').on('click','li.active',function(){
//do the logic for active buttons here
});
```

Now toggle the class active on li element to enable/disable the custom part.

And with single event listener you can do something like

```
$('body').on('click','li',function(){
     //do common stuff
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
      //do stuff
      }
    else{
      //do other stuff
      }
    });
```

For both cases

$(elem).toggleClass('active');

will toggle running of the custom part

And your case:

```
$('.head2, .head3').click(function(event) {
    var object = $(this).siblings('.head4');
    if (something) object.siblings('.head3').children('.primary').addClass('active');
    if (somethingelse)object.siblings('.head3').children('.primary').removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `F1()` and `F2()` in all three handlers, but you are not calling them so they are never executed.  You need to call them if you want them to run.  *[EDIT - OP has fixed this first issue - the second issue still remains].*

I also don't see what you're actually trying to accomplish because in the first two cases, the `F1()` function removes the click handlers, but the `F2()` function doesn't install new working handlers because it has no event handler callback.  The callback function is not optional for `.on()`.

---

I think the idea to use delegated event handling is probably the simplest here.

When installing the event handlers for .head3 objects, don't install them directly on the objects.  Instead, install them on a parent object.  You can then just add or remove a class from the target objects in order to enable or disable the event handlers:

```
// the click handlers for .head3 objects
// these will only fire if the .head3 object does not have the disabled class on it
$(document.body).on('click', '.head3:not(.disabled) > .primary', function() {
    // your .head3 click handler code goes here
});

// then, turn an event handler on or off, you just add or remove the disabled class
// from it
$('.head2, .head3').click(function(event) {
    var object = $(this).siblings('.head4');
    function F1() {
        object.siblings('.head3').children('.primary').addClass("disabled");
    }
    function F2() {
        object.siblings('.head3').children('.primary').removeClass("disabled");
    }
    if (something) F1();
    if (somethingelse) F2();
});
```

Now, you haven't shown any of your HTML nor fully described what you're really trying to do, but this illustrates the general idea.

Comment: will switching off click just disable it or remove respective eventListeners, if it removes will it comeback when doing 'on'?

Comment: @sabithpocker - `.off()` removes the event handlers completely.  You have to fully reinstall from scratch with `.on()` including the event handler function.  You an see in the [`.on()` doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/) that the event handler is not an optional argument.

Comment: @jfriend00 He might need to delegate from body and just switch the classes to enable/disble right?

Comment: @AaronWalker - So now that you're calling them, you have to fix the `.on()` calls to have the desired event handlers in them.  You can't just call `.on()`.  If we had a better picture of what you're really trying to do, then we could probably suggest a much more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: @sabithpocker, how would I reinstall the function with .on() function?

Comment: @sabithpocker - yeah delegated event handling with adding/removing classes might be a useful idea here.  Or, the event handler itself could just check a flag or class on the object.

Comment: @AaronWalker - the same way it was installed originally.  You have to pass the event and the event handler function to `.on('click', yourFunction)`.

Comment: @AaronWalker You want to disbale/enebele click or do you want to swap event handlers, please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: @AaronWalker - in your third attempt, `func` has to be a valid function that you want to be the event handler.  I can't tell from your code what it is.  Please back up and describe (in your question) the full problem you're trying to solve so we can advise you on the best way to approach it.  You are down in the weeds of a complicated way to do this.  There are very, very likely better and simpler ways to do this.

Comment: @AaronWalker In your third attempt the value of func should be a jQuery Object corresponding to $('.head2 li, .head3 li') and not the click event handler as you may be guessing, as jfriend00 suggested please clarify the question

Comment: @AaronWalker - I added a different way of doing this using delegated event handling.  It's a more advanced method of event handling, but is perfect for dynamically changing which objects respond to an event handler without having to add/remove event handlers themselves.  Using this technique, you can just add/remove a class from the target object to turn one specific event handler on/off.

Comment: Wow, I think that's the most work I've ever put into an answer and not even gotten a single upvote. Oh well, that's the way the cookie crumbles sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you jfriend00 and sabithpocker for you continuous help.

I was putting the variable `func` in the wrong spot. I put it equal to the function, instead of the listener.

```
$('.head2 li, .head3 li').click(func = function(event) {
    var object = $(this).parent().siblings('.head4');
    if (something) F1();
if (somethingelse)) F2();
    function F1() {
        object.siblings('.head3').children('.primary').off('click');
    }
    function F2() {
        object.siblings('.head3').children('.primary').on('click', func);
    }
});
```

Comment: you are still doing it the hard way it seems

Comment: @sabithpocker Haha. How else would it be?